# How to move/align a piechart in R within margins

Tags: r, plot, label, alignment, pie-chart

I made a piechart in R, but the label is covering the plot. How do I move the plot to the left to see the full plot?

Right now my code is

```
pie(slices_Pjob_rel, labels = lbls_Pjob_rel, cex = .6, main="Participant Household Job Holders", radius = 1,
    col = c("skyblue3","lightcyan1"))
legend("right", c("1: mother", "2: father", "3: sister", "4: brother", 
                     "5: aunt", "6: uncle", "7: other female relative", 
                     "8: other male relative"), cex = 0.8)
```

Giving me the following:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6hX7V.png)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust the margins of the plot using with `par` (includes the bottom, left, top and right margins respectively).

You can set the location of your legend by providing an `x` and `y` value in your `legend` function.

Here's the result with example data:

```
# Make example slices and labels
slices <- c(5, 15, 8, 12, 10, 15, 30, 5)
slices_labels <- 1:8

# Adjust margins
par(mar=c(2,0,2,2))

# Draw pie chart
pie(slices, labels = slices_labels, cex = .6, main="Participant Household Job Holders", radius = 1,
    col = c("skyblue3","lightcyan1"))

# Add legend specifying x and y
legend(x = 1.2, y = .3, c("1: mother", "2: father", "3: sister", "4: brother", 
                  "5: aunt", "6: uncle", "7: other female relative", 
                  "8: other male relative"), cex = 0.8)
```

[image: example plot with legend]